# What is causing this in my React Native App : AsyncStorage Issue

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I'm getting some weird data when I save data into the AsyncStorage and Try to pull it back out.

It starts on my login.js file.  (This appears to be ok but here is the code I'm using to save)

Login.js

```
AsyncStorage.setItem("announcementData", JSON.stringify(result.data.Announcements));
AsyncStorage.setItem("token", JSON.stringify(result.data.token));
props.navigation.navigate('Home');
```

Now, My Home.js

if I do this without the 'await' tag I get an array of promises???

```
const announceArr = AsyncStorage.getItem('announcementData') || [];
//const announceArrParsed = JSON.parse(announceArr);
console.log(announceArr);
```

Output:

```
Promise {
  "_40": 0,
  "_55": null,
  "_65": 0,
  "_72": null,
}
Promise {
  "_40": 0,
  "_55": null,
  "_65": 0,
  "_72": null,
}

[Unhandled promise rejection: Invariant Violation: Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {_40, _65, _55, _72}). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead.]
```

If I put an 'await' tag on it...

```
const announceArr = await AsyncStorage.getItem('announcementData') || [];
//const announceArrParsed = JSON.parse(announceArr);
console.log(announceArr);
```

Output:

```
[{"AnnouncementId":1,"Title":"Welcome to the new SLSWAY!","Description":"Please take some time and review our new site.","DivisionId":1,"IsActive":true,"CreatedOn":"2019-12-11T15:54:39","CreatedById":1,"DivisionName":"Face to Face"},{"AnnouncementId":2,"Title":"Contest Alert","Description":"Make sure you take advantage of the Floss like A Boss Contest! Details are in your email. NEORC!","DivisionId":1,"IsActive":true,"CreatedOn":"2019-12-11T15:57:31","CreatedById":1,"DivisionName":"Face to Face"}]
[{"AnnouncementId":1,"Title":"Welcome to the new SLSWAY!","Description":"Please take some time and review our new site.","DivisionId":1,"IsActive":true,"CreatedOn":"2019-12-11T15:54:39","CreatedById":1,"DivisionName":"Face to Face"},{"AnnouncementId":2,"Title":"Contest Alert","Description":"Make sure you take advantage of the Floss like A Boss Contest! Details are in your email. NEORC!","DivisionId":1,"IsActive":true,"CreatedOn":"2019-12-11T15:57:31","CreatedById":1,"DivisionName":"Face to Face"}]
```

Error Im still seeing...

```
[Unhandled promise rejection: Invariant Violation: Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {_40, _65, _55, _72}). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead.]
```

Just to test another angle, I wrote this code...

```
let announceDataParsed;
    await AsyncStorage.getItem('announcementData').then((result) => {
        announceDataParsed = JSON.parse(result);
        console.log(announceDataParsed);
    });
```

Output:

```
Array [
  Object {
    "AnnouncementId": 1,
    "CreatedById": 1,
    "CreatedOn": "2019-12-11T15:54:39",
    "Description": "Please take some time and review our new site.",
    "DivisionId": 1,
    "DivisionName": "Face to Face",
    "IsActive": true,
    "Title": "Welcome to the new SLSWAY!",
  },
  Object {
    "AnnouncementId": 2,
    "CreatedById": 1,
    "CreatedOn": "2019-12-11T15:57:31",
    "Description": "Make sure you take advantage of the Floss like A Boss Contest! Details are in your email. NEORC!",
    "DivisionId": 1,
    "DivisionName": "Face to Face",
    "IsActive": true,
    "Title": "Contest Alert",
  },
]
Array [
  Object {
    "AnnouncementId": 1,
    "CreatedById": 1,
    "CreatedOn": "2019-12-11T15:54:39",
    "Description": "Please take some time and review our new site.",
    "DivisionId": 1,
    "DivisionName": "Face to Face",
    "IsActive": true,
    "Title": "Welcome to the new SLSWAY!",
  },
  Object {
    "AnnouncementId": 2,
    "CreatedById": 1,
    "CreatedOn": "2019-12-11T15:57:31",
    "Description": "Make sure you take advantage of the Floss like A Boss Contest! Details are in your email. NEORC!",
    "DivisionId": 1,
    "DivisionName": "Face to Face",
    "IsActive": true,
    "Title": "Contest Alert",
  },
]
```

Put I still see this error???

```
[Unhandled promise rejection: Invariant Violation: Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {_40, _65, _55, _72}). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead.]
```

What is causing this???

Is it a async issue? and why do I suddenly see double arrays of data???  Am I just doing something wrong.  I'm not outputting this out yet in HTML / Views yet, just tracing data and console logging...

Please Help, I'm totally lost why this is going crazy

Comment: Where are you doing that? Would you share all code when you are doing this?

Comment: its not async issue.. if you could tell us where you are using that data that would be more helpful

Comment: You have to enclose the await call in a `try/catch` block. That's why you're getting Unhandled Promise Rejection warning